# Retrieve data from JSON with where statement

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file with a structure like this:

```
{
    "gasStationID":"441",
    "gasStationLat":"39.6337420",
    "gasStationLong":"22.4324412",
    "fuelCompID":"6",
    "fuelCompNormalName":"AVIN",
    "ddID":"42010100",
    "municipalityID":"42010000",
    "countyID":"42000000",
    "phone1":null,
    "username":"user1",
    "fuelTypeID":"1",
    "fuelPrice":"1.379"
},
{
    "gasStationID":"441",
    "gasStationLat":"39.6337420",
    "gasStationLong":"22.4324412",
    "fuelCompID":"6",
    "fuelCompNormalName":"AVIN",
    "ddID":"42010100",
    "municipalityID":"42010000",
    "countyID":"42000000",
    "phone1":null,
    "username":"user1",
    "fuelTypeID":"1",
    "fuelPrice":"1.478"
}
```

So, my question is how to retrieve the `fuelPrice` with `fuelTypeID=1`?

My JavaScript file is this:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var _gasStationCompName = obj[i].fuelCompNormalName;
    var priceID = obj[i].fuelTypeID;
    switch (fuelId) {
        case '1':
        case priceID == 1:
            price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
            break;
        case '2':
        case priceID == 2:
            price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
            break;
        default:
            price = "0";
    }
```

My problem is that in the `price = obj[i].fuelPrice` is showing only the `fuelPrice` with `fuelType=2`. How can I filter inside the switch statement the result?

Before that I'm parsing the JSON file. Also, you can see that I have `case: '1'`. That's because I have something like this in my HTML file:

```
<div>
        <select onChange="getData(this.value);">
            <option value="1">Gas</option>
            <option value="2">Diesel</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea, like check yer varaible names man

Comment: I edited the post and fixed the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. Here is the right switch statement that works like a charm:

```
                       var priceID = obj[i].fuelTypeID;
                        switch (fuelTypeID) {
                            case '1':
                                if (priceID == 1) {
                                    price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
                                }
                                break;
                            case '2':
                                if (priceID == 2) {
                                    price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                price = 0;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables, and objects keys are case sensitive (A != a);

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var _gasStationCompName = obj[i].fuelCompNormalName;
  var priceID = obj[i].fuelTypeID; // fuelTypeId => fuelTypeID
  switch (priceID) { fuelTypeId // => priceID 
      case '1':
      case priceID == 1:
          price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
          break;
      case '2':
      case priceID == 2:
          price = obj[i].fuelPrice;
          break;
      default:
          price = "0";
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. In the switch statement I switch the value from the `<select>` because I want to check what the user have selected. If he has selected "Gas" I want the `fuelPrice` with `fuelTypeID=1` etc. So, if I change the switched value with `priceID` I don't get any values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the JSON is an array. Let's call that array `gasStations`.

```
// Given a collection of stations and a fuel type, find the price

function findPrice(collection, fuelType) {
  // Find the station with the target fuel type
  var targetStation = collection.filter(function (station) {
    return station.fuelTypeID === fuelType;
  })[0];

  // If there was a match, return that station's price
  if (targetStation) {
    return targetStation.fuelPrice;
  }

  // Default to "0" if there was no match
  return "0";
}

// usage
var price = findPrice(gasStations, "1");
```

Note: If you have a collection where more than one station has the target fuel type, this function will return the price of the first gas station that has that fuel type.

Comment: This function didn't work in my case. Every gasStation has two or more types of fuel (gas, diesel etc). If you you saw I have `<select>` which I want to select the type and the prices will change live. The `fuelId` in the switch statement is different from `fuelTypeID` in JSON file. I switch the value from the `<select>` to see what the user have chosen.